# Networking : DHCP/static : connection to LAN but not to internet

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

I have a problem to connect the Raspberry Pi to the Internet.

`ping 8.8.8.8` does not work, but the Pi can be accessed using SSH with my laptop on the same network.

My laptop and the Pi use ethernet and are plugged directly into the router (Freebox). For my laptop, `ping 8.8.8.8` works.

Some set up from the Pi:

#### `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet static
    address 88.168.64.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 88.168.64.254
```

#### `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 88.168.64.254
```

#### `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         88.168.64.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

88.168.64.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I noticed that my laptop had a third route:

```
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

Thus I added this route to the Pi but it didn't change anything.

I wondered whether the MAC address of the Pi (`b8:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`) was accepted by the router because I also tried DHCP and in the logs I had no IP returned by `dhcpoffer`:

```
dhclient: DHCPOFFER from 88.168.64.254
```

Thus, maybe I should check the router configuration but I need a password to connect to it and I don't have it. Another solution may be to connect the Pi to my laptop, but I have only one ethernet port. I could also use WiFi but I have no idea of SSID + password.

Why can I not get connectivity from the Ethernet side?

Comment: I doubt you can just use the IP address 88.168.64.5. That's a proxad owned IP. Try giving it a similar IP to what your PC is getting. Something like 192.168.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 1):

What sort of router is this ? Is it actually a modem ? Will it only let one device online at a time ?

We need some more details on how things are setup, Which ISP you are with, what modem or router you're using etc.
The fact that your Pi is getting a 88.168.64.x IP Address is suspect...

I'm suspecting you have a modem, and not a router, which will only let one device online at a time, even if it keeps handing out IP Addresses.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace static ip address with:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and enjoy DHCP assigned address along with the internet connection.

Comment: I tried DHCP by replacing
iface eth0 inet static

address 88.168.64.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 88.168.64.254

by iface eth0 inet dhcp

But I did not find the Pi using nmap -sP 88.168.64.*, no new IP and watching the Pi logs, no IP returned by DHCPOFFER.

Comment: your router is supposed to give away DHCP address in the range 192.168.XX.XXX, no wonder you cannot find anything in 88.168.64.*

Comment: even if the netmask was 255.255.255.0 ? My laptop uses DHCP but its local IP is 88.168.64.188.

Comment: routers are supposed to give away addresses in preallocated ranges, for home routers it's usually 192.168.xx.yyy, usually `xx` is fixed to some small number, like 15, and the last three digits are incremented for every new device requesting DHCP address.

Comment: but in my case 192 is 88 right ?

Comment: 88.xxx.xxx.xx is the address your provider has assigned to your modem or router, depending on how your network is configured. the addresses of devices behind the router are supposed to be something like 192.168.xx.xxx

Comment: my laptop connected to my router has 88.168.64.188 as IP address : that would mean my router is badly set up ?

Comment: you should check where did you laptop got this address from. and router configuration issues are probably offtopic in raspberry pi section.

Comment: In /var/log/syslog, I have : DHCPOFFER of 88.168.64.188 from 88.168.64.254. This shows that my router (88.168.64.254) gives the IP 88.168.64.188 to my laptop, right ? But my laptop has internet even if it does not have an IP beginning by 192. Thus, do you think the problem comes from my router or from the Pi set up ? Thanks by advance for your reply.

Comment: Raspberry Pi (raspbian) usually works perfectly without any configuration, your router might be the problem, because it assigns global addresses from the space that does not belong to your local network.

Comment: As Lawrence has mentioned above, you are probably plugged directly into a modem, or your router is bridged, and the IP you are receiving is from your ISP not the router.

Answer (score 0):

I realize now that my Pi is only connected to my laptop :

**arp -n :**

Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface

88.168.64.188            ether   00:1e:ec:ba:b2:8a   C                     eth0

**whereas my laptop is connected to my Pi but also to the router :**

88.168.64.254            ether   00:24:d4:c3:d2:53   C                     eth0

88.168.64.189            ether   b8:27:eb:fb:6d:68   C                     eth0

**That's strange because the Pi routes mentions the default one with the router IP :**

0.0.0.0         88.168.64.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

I tried to use a static IP address for the Pi : 169.254.64.189, but impossible to connect.

**Thus, what explains the fact that the Pi has a route through the router (route -n shows the router) but does not get the router IP while doing an ARP (arp -n) ?**